# Disable autoconfiguration for Spring Cloud Config in a test class of a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a test class annotated with `@DataJpaTest` which autoconfigures Cloud Config.

I want to stop that for that one test class. I cannot use the `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` application property, because that would disable it for all tests.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`@DataJpaTest` takes a `excludeAutoConfiguration` argument. You can specify all the AutoConfig's which you want to exclude.

```
@DataJpaTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = {AbcCloudAutoConfig.class, DefCloudAutoConfig.class})
```

replace AbcCloudAutoConfig, DefCloudAutoConfig with the classes you want to exclude

Answer (score 1):

@DataJpaTest annotation has other attributes.  I tried the following to specifically disable the Spring Cloud Config and it worked for me locally:

```java
@DataJpaTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false"})
```